# How can I fix Android Market app's "Allow Automatic Updating" checkbox after it hid?

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I ran into a really weird problem (bug?)

In Android Market, when looking at a specific application's info, the first area in the lower white half of the screen is "**Updates**", containing "Allow Automatic Updating" check-box.

When I try to click on the check-box and miss even a little, the whole area containing the check-box **disappears** completely (the next "My Review" area becomes top-most).

I can not seem to get back the area for that app, even after reloading its info, or even killing Market app.

1. Is this a bug? A design feature?
2. How can I get back the Update checkbox-containing area from wherever it's hiding?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a design feature ... I'm not able to reproduce this at all (except for scrolling down a bit :).

However, as the Android Market App isn't the most stable app on the Android platform, you might want to try clearing the market app cache.

Go to Settings - Applications - Manage Applications - Select Android Market App  - Click the Clear Cache button.

Restart the Market app and check if the checkbox is present.

Comment: I will try that, thanks. I am almost certain that it will do the trick.

Comment: I have to clear both cache and data to get the checkbox back when this happens (it's fairly infrequent, at least...)

Comment: Market app is really sluggish on my phone (Galaxy S), a lousy experience. never had the checkbox issue though...